# For loop file name to see if it contains any of the possible?

Tags: batch-file

Somehow can I use a for loop (/R) to see if a file name contains one of three or more different parts?

```
for /R "C:\" %%A in ("*.*") do (
if %%~nxA==a*.txt echo a
if %%~nxA==*b.txt echo b

)
```

etc.?

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following should give the logic that you have specified:

```
for /r "c:\" %%F in ("a*.txt" "*b.txt") do echo %%F
```

or

```
dir /s /b /a-d "c:\a*.txt" "c:\*b.txt"
```

***BUT***, you must realize that you could get duplicate listings because a file like "a_b.txt" would match both masks - Each mask is listed separately.

You could use the following to get distinct values:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "prior="
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /s /b /a-d "c:\a*.txt" "c:\*b.txt" ^| sort'
) do (
  set "now=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if !now! neq !prior! echo !now!
  endlocal
  set "prior=%%F"
)
```

Or you could use my [JSORT.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) to conveniently and efficiently sort and remove duplicates. JSORT.BAT is pure script (JScript/batch hybrid) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
dir /s /b /a-d "c:\a*.txt" "c:\*b.txt" | jsort /u
```